# Multiple if and elseif don't work properly

Tags: php, mysql

user is asked to select location and cuisine to search for restaurant nearby. now if user only select particular cuisine all restaurant with that cuisine should be selected from database and same case location... here it is only echo first part not other two condition.. please help!! please don't consider injection
php part on which user is redirected is given below..

```
<?php

    if(isset($_REQUEST['location']) && $_REQUEST['cuisine'])
    {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `restaurant` WHERE `location_id`='".$_REQUEST['location']."' and `cuisine_id`='".$_REQUEST['cuisine']."' ORDER BY restaurant_name ";
        echo"qu";
    }
    elseif(isset($_REQUEST['location']) && $_REQUEST['cuisine'] ='all cuisine')
    {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `restaurant` WHERE `location_id`='".$_REQUEST['location']."' ORDER BY restaurant_name ";
        echo"here are result";
    }
    elseif(isset($_REQUEST['cuisine']) && $_REQUEST['location'] ='all location')
    {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `restaurant` WHERE `cuisine_id`='".$_REQUEST['cuisine']."' ORDER BY restaurant_name ";
        echo"query";
    }
    else
    {
        echo"no result found";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Make sure to escape your raw input. Having queries with inline $REQUEST variables is a **huge security risk** (sql injection). In the queries, simply surround $_REQUEST['key'] with mysql_real_escape_string, like so: mysql_real_escape_string($REQUEST['key']) (if you're under php 5.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `$_REQUEST['cuisine']` to equal "all cuisine", the variable `$_REQUEST['cuisine']` will need to be set in the first place. Ditto for location.

As such, `isset($_REQUEST['cuisine'])` will be true whenever `$_REQUEST['cuisine'] === 'all cuisine'` is true (again ditto location), which is why those two cases will never occur -- they are both preempted by `isset($_REQUEST['location'] && $_REQUEST['cuisine'])`.

I think what you're looking for is:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_REQUEST['location'], $_REQUEST['cuisine']))
    {
        if($_REQUEST['cuisine'] === 'all cuisine')
        {
            $sql="SELECT * FROM `restaurant` WHERE `location_id`='".$_REQUEST['location']."' ORDER BY restaurant_name ";
            echo"here are result";
        }
        elseif($_REQUEST['location'] === 'all location')
        {
            $sql="SELECT * FROM `restaurant` WHERE `cuisine_id`='".$_REQUEST['cuisine']."' ORDER BY restaurant_name ";
            echo"query";
        }
        else
        {
            $sql="SELECT * FROM `restaurant` WHERE `location_id`='".$_REQUEST['location']."' and `cuisine_id`='".$_REQUEST['cuisine']."' ORDER BY restaurant_name ";
            echo"qu";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo"no result found";
    }
?>
```

PS: Per other comments, http://php.net/ternary is also worth noting.

Comment: This will fail if $_REQUEST['cuisine'] is not set at all. There's mistake with parenthesis of isset() in first line.

Comment: Thanks @DarkSide -- my code rearrangement got a bit confused at one point. Fixed now. :-)

Comment: I also fixed isset to pass multiple parameters properly, per http://www.php.net/isset

Comment: Added mysqli_real_escape_string. That's mandatory thing to do when injecting received input in SQL expressions. Also slightly simplified expressions by using temporary variables $loc and $cui.

Comment: Definitely great advice, although the OP specifically asked not to consider injection. (Not sure why -- might be for a reason, or might just be to avoid info overload.) For reference though, http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php is vital for guarding against injection, and you should pull location and cuisine into `$loc = $_REQUEST['location']` etc directly after the "isset()" check within the subblock, so that the SQL strings can be simplified to `WHERE \`location_id\`='$loc'` etc. Credit to @DarkSide for safety checks and improvements.

Answer (score 2):

```
$_REQUEST['cuisine'] ='all cuisine'
```

should be

```
$_REQUEST['cuisine'] == 'all cuisine'
```

`if ($a= 'a')` will return true, its will not compare.

If you want to compare it has to be

```
if($a == 'a')
```

so here is an example

```
$a = 'b';
if($a = 'a'){
    echo 'here';
}else{
    echo 'not here';
}
```

This will output `here`

check here  http://php.net/ternary

Comment: and the same for `$_REQUEST['location']`

Comment: @JamesHalsall I agree. +1

Comment: you're also better using `===` in this case

Comment: @JamesHalsall yes same for $_REQUEST['location']

Comment: Please add this link in your post http://php.net/ternary and this is not true "($a= 'a') will always return true". It'll return 'a' not true, but it works in this case because 'a' ir not null or empty. But if you place '0' instead of 'a' then you'll see very ugly difference :)

Comment: it only echoes 'qu' whatever condition i give

Comment: Because all this if elseif statement is absolutely wrong! You're missing isset() for many fields and ... there are more mistakes than ants in their "den".

Comment: @user2819264 -- The first if clause is preempting the others. Scope out my answer and see if it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Single `=` assigns a value, whereas `==` returns true if value on the left side equals that on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
// field name in DB => field name in REQUEST
$fields = array('location_id'=>'location', 'cuisine_id'=>'cuisine');

$cond = array();
foreach($fields as $f=>$p) {
    $v = isset($_REQUEST[$p]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST[$p]) : null;
    if($v && $v!=="all $p") {
        $cond[] = "`$f`='$v'";
    }
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `restaurant` WHERE " . join(' AND ', $cond) . " ORDER BY restaurant_name";

// execute $sql query
// ...
```

Comment: can you please explain the logic for using join ?

Comment: join() or implode() will merge array elements and put ' AND ' between them and return string like "foo AND bar AND baz". I'm not telling that this is the best way to do this. You can still use IF conditions if you like. But this way this code snippet will be very easy to configure. For example, if you need one more field, then you can simply add it in $fields array in first row and ... that's all.

Comment: i didn't understand this format $v = isset($_REQUEST[$p]) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST[$p]) : null;
    if($v && $v!=="all $p") {
        $cond[] = "`$f`='$v'"

Comment: Please read http://us2.php.net/ternary very carefully line by line. If you don't understand that then you're way to far from being kind of successful programmer mate:)

Comment: The expression (expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3) evaluates to expr2 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 if expr1 evaluates to FALSE.
Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.